# Sqlite create database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I'm new to sqlite, and i've been for a couple of days trying to follow a tutorial, but it do not want to add my database and table. It gives me the alert that i've made if the table is not added. "the TABLE has not been created"

i do not get any xcode errors, so it could be something else than this code i guess. anybody have any suggestions?

viewcontroller.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *databaseName, *tableName;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) int numberOfRows;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dataList;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) BOOL table_ok, db_open_status;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *my_columns_names;
```

viewcontroller.h

```
[super viewDidLoad];
dataList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
numberOfRows = 0;
databaseName = @"mysampledatabase";
tableName = @"mypeople";
db_open_status = NO;
table_ok = NO;
my_columns_names = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"hometeam",@"awayteam",@"homeplayers",@"homefouls",@"awayplayers",@"awayfouls",@"period",@"time",@"homescore",@"awayscore", nil];
if ([self openDBWithSQLName:databaseName]) {
    db_open_status = YES;
    if (![self createTable:tableName WithCoulumns:my_columns_names]) {
        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"the TABLE has not been created" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [av show];
    } else {
        table_ok = YES;
    }
}


-(BOOL)openDBWithSQLName:(NSString *)sqlname{
    BOOL is_Opened = NO;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *my_sqlfile = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:sqlname];
    if (sqlite3_open([my_sqlfile UTF8String], &dbname) ==SQLITE_OK) {
        is_Opened = YES;
    }
    return is_Opened;

}


-(BOOL)createTable:(NSString *)tablename WithCoulumns:(NSArray *)columnNames{
    BOOL has_beencreated = NO;
    NSString *fieldset = @"";
    char *err;
    for (int a=0; a<[columnNames count]; a++){

        NSString *columnSet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' TEXT", [columnNames objectAtIndex:a]];
        fieldset = [fieldset stringByAppendingString:columnSet];
        if (a<([columnNames count]-1)) {
            fieldset = [fieldset stringByAppendingString:@" ,"];
        }

    }
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '%@' (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,%@", tableName, fieldset];
    if (sqlite3_exec(dbname, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(dbname);
    } else {
        has_beencreated = YES;
    }
    return has_beencreated;
}
```

Comment: What are the methods for createTable:WithCoulumns: and openDBWithSQLName:? Show them as well.

Comment: Ohh sorry i forgot. here you go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the issue with the  "the TABLE has not been created" message you receive (I did, as well!). In the createTable: method just before the assignment of ***sql** if you add this code:
`fieldset=[fieldset stringByAppendingString:@")"];`

the fiedlset is fulfilled with a closing bracket that it misses. 
You can check it yourself by putting a breakpoint a little below this at:

```
has_beencreated = YES;
```

run the app and check the variable **&err**

Hope it helps!